# Unsure why we are setting currentQuestionIndex = 0 in this part of the code

Tags: swift3

Ive just started to learn programming via swift and am unsure why the currentQuestionIndex = 0 is used here. I understand that currentQuestionIndex refers to where I am in my array, but why are we setting it to 0 here?

[Is this saying let the initial currentQuestionIndex be 0 and then add one to it everytime I click nextQuestion button?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM8Fa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the index to 0 when your increment reaches the number of items will make it return to the first item when you go beyond the last one.